# my php form will not work and i have no idea why

Tags: php, forms, validation, email

what i need is to know why my form will not send it just keeps sending the me the same generic error and everything matches up i think the regular exspressions are the problem but im not sure... 
the form code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>register</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/eight.css"/>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/valid.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
<a href="../home.html"><div class="tile amarelo">
        <span class="t">Home</span><br/>
        </div></a><BR><BR>
<center>

<form name="signup" method="post" action="send_form_member.php">

<table width="450px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="firstName">First Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="firstName" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top"">

  <label for="lastName">Last Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="lastName" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="address">street address *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="address" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

 <tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="city">city *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="city" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

 <tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="state">state *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="state" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

 <tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="zip">zip *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="zip" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

 <tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="phoneNumber">phone number *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="phoneNumber" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="username">Username</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="password">password *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>


 <tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="DOB">DOB *(mm/dd/yyyy)</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="DOB" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">   

 </td>

</tr>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

the php check and e-mail sender is :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {





    $email_to = "my e-mail";

    $email_subject = "Signed up";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['firstName']) ||

        !isset($_POST['lastName']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['phoneNumber']) ||

        !isset($_POST ['address']) ||

        !isset($_POST['city']) ||

        !isset($_POST['state']) ||

        !isset($_POST['zip']) ||

        !isset ($_POST['username']) ||

        !isset ($_POST['password']) ||

        !isset ($_POST['DOB']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comment'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $firstName = $_POST['firstName']; // required

    $lastName = $_POST['lastName']; // required

    $address = $_POST['address']; //reuired

    $city = $_POST['city']; // required

    $state = $_POST['state']; // required

    $zip = $_POST['zip']; // required

    $username = $_POST['username']; //required

    $password = $_POST['password']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $phoneNumber = $_POST['phoneNumber']; // required

    $DOB = $_POST['DOB']; // required in JS but not php yet





    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$firstName)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$lastName)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z0-9.'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$address)) {

    $error_message .= 'The address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$city)) {

    $error_message .= 'The city you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$state)) {

    $error_message .= 'The state you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  $string_exp = "/^[0-9 .'-]+$/";
   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$zip)) {

    $error_message .= 'The zip you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  $string_exp = "/^[0-9 .'-]+$/";
   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$phoneNumber)) {

    $error_message .= 'The phone number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  $string_exp = "/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/";
   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$username)) {

    $error_message .= 'The username you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  $string_exp = "/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*$/";
   if(!preg_match($string_exp,$password)) {

    $error_message .= 'The password you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }



  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($firstName)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($lastName)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Address: ".clean_string($address)."\n";

    $email_message .= "city: ".clean_string($city)."\n";

    $email_message .= "state: ".clean_string($state)."\n";

    $email_message .= "zip: ".clean_string($zip)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Phone number: ".clean_string($phoneNumber)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Username: ".clean_string($username)."\n";

    $email_message .= "password: ".clean_string($password)."\n";

    $email_message .= "DOB: ".clean_string($DOB)."\n";







// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

?>
```

for the whole website idea visit  www.photofundesigns.com

Comment: What is _the same generic error_?

Comment: What have you tried ? What's the error ? When did it occur ? Some many questions we could ask...

Comment: Narrow the problem down.  Delete chunks of code until the problem starts.

Comment: You don't have an `input` with `name="comment"` but you do check for it.

Comment: It shouldn't matter too much, but you never close your `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for a form field with `name="comment"` which doesn't exist.
So you either need to add a field with `name="comment"` to your `form` or remove `|| !isset($_POST['comment'])`

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite

```
!isset ($_POST['DOB']) ||
!isset($_POST['comment']))
```

as

```
!isset ($_POST['DOB']))
```

Your html does not have a comment input box.